# Yammer embed SharePoint Online (default groups, open graph objects removal)

Tags: office365, yammer, sharepoint-online

Im trying to implement yammer feed into SharePoint Online as commenting platform for pages, but I cant find correct solution for those issues :

1. I created yammer group for posting and also set it as default group id, this display as well, but still the user is able to change it to different one in UI of the yammer embed, which I would like to deny.Is there any option for this? I dont want to that users are able to post the comments in different group instead of the default one.
2. The open graph post to yammer is not working correctly, when Im posting a comment and erase the preview at the time Im posting the comment, so it will create a yammer comment, but it will lose the connection to the SharePoint Online page itself. It is somehow possible to deny the users to erase the connection at the time of the comment post?

[Issues mentioned in point 1&2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwNQa.png)

The script is :

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
"network": "xxyy.onmicrosoft.com",
"feedType": "open-graph",
"config": {
"defaultGroupId": 12345678,
"use_sso": true,
"header": false,
"footer": false,
"showOpenGraphPreview": false,
"defaultToCanonical": true,
"hideNetworkName": false,
"promptText": "Comment on this article"
},
"objectProperties": {
"url": location.href,
"description" : " Comments feed for page ",
"title": document.title,
"type": "page",
"ignore_canonical_url": false
},
"container": "#embedded-feed"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few additional tests, I discovered that there is no way in current version of Yammer Embed to deny those "features" (bugs), only possible way is to develop own custom yammer WP.